# Annualized return of bond fund

Tags: bonds, rate-of-return

How do you calculate the say a 10-year annualized return of FTSE TMX Canada High Yield Bond Index. Please dumb it down as to the process.

Answer (score 1):

For *price* return you just look at the ending price relative to the beginning price. The formula is

```
R = ((endPrice/begPrice - 1) ^ (1/n)) - 1
```

This is the inverse of the growth function

```
end = beg * (1+r)^n
```

For *total* return (meaning how much will I earn if I reinvest dividends and capital gains), just all all distributions to `endPrice`.